# Separate process Windows Exe Program and Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've made a windows service program with c# in visual studio. When I run this program the process tree is show as below.

[image]

Is there anyway  to separate those two marked???

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"? I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: i mean like starting the service in a different thread so that the the service is the parent process